# GroupBy week/month

Tags: c#, linq, datetime, group-by

I'm getting list of products from a database, each of them have populated paymentDate and I would like to format my data like this (just an example):

```
{ 
  Week:1,
  Month:8,
  Total:50
},
{ 
  Week:2,
  Month:8,
  Total:40
},
{ 
   Week:3,
   Month:8,
   Total:70
},
{ 
   Week:4,
   Month:8,
   Total:85
 }
... and so on..
```

Now I'm getting my data grouped by month and for **4** months it returns 4 INSTEAD OF **16** rows like:

```
Month:8,
Total:250
```

And that's what I don't want..

Here's my code:

First I'm getting all rows from a last 4 months from a database, there is like 20-30 rows with `PaymentDate` value (which are rows from last 4 months).

```
var yas = await _context.products
                .AsNoTracking()
                .Where(x => (x.PaymentDate != null && x.PaymentDate > DateTime.UtcNow.AddMonths(-4))).ToListAsync();
```

After I get all rows, I'm trying to group them on a way to get data grouped by WEEKS in each MONTH.

```
var grouped = yas.GroupBy(x => CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(x.PaymentDate ?? DateTime.UtcNow, CalendarWeekRule.FirstDay, DayOfWeek.Monday))
                    .Select(product => new ProductsDemoData
                    {
                        //Week = should be week
                        Amount = product.Sum(x => x.Amount),
                        Month = product.FirstOrDefault().PaymentDate.Value.Month
                    });
```

Example of data:

[image]

Comment: This should result in something that would have week 1 in month 1, not 8 because that's giving you the week of the year.  Do you instead want week of the month?

Comment: @juharr in my yas variable there is result of 3 months so there should be like 9 weeks..

Comment: @Jon what do you think mate?

Comment: @Roxy'Pro: How come you expect to get 16 rows? Please provide some sample data.

Comment: @mm8 this variable `yas` holds like 20 products (5 from Jan, 5 from Feb, 5 from March, 5 from April)... and each of those 20 products has ProductDate and I would like to group those rows as in example I posted above, I will exapand it now little bit. (Basically grouping by month - and by a week in a month where I would get Week: 3, Total Amount for items in Week 3 is like 50..

Comment: Do you have data in each of the 16 weeks?  Because it's only going to return the week that you actually have data for.  Also weeks of the year will not be confined to a single month.  You can have a week that starts in one month and ends in the next.

Comment: I still do not understand why you would get Week 1 with Month 8.  You even state that you're data is only for Jan-April so you should only ever have months 1-4.

Comment: @Roxy'Pro: Please include a compilable `yas` populated with sample data in your question.

Comment: @mm8 there it's

Comment: @mm8 I will post example with array data in a 5 minutes

Comment: @mm8 I've posted example of data and how I would expect it in app (Month 9 week 1  Amount 100, Month 9 Week 2 Amount 130) and so on.. :)

Comment: @Roxy'Pro: You have added an image. You are supposed to provide some code that anyone can copy and paste to reproduce your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1):

you've grouped by Week, so you can just do this I think:

```
.Select(product => new ProductsDemoData
                {
                    Week = product.Key,
                    Amount = product.Sum(x => x.Amount),
                    Month = product.FirstOrDefault().PaymentDate.Value.Month
                });
```

Comment: what's the key there?

Comment: @Roxy'Pro The `Key` is what you grouped on, in this case the week number

Comment: in your `Select`, you are operating on the results of a `GroupBy` expression, which is (IIRC) an `IGrouping`.  each item in such a list has a `Key` property which is the thing that was grouped by.

Comment: @GPW I think it aint work because I'm getting 4 rows instead of 16, group by is not allright.. I should get like 16 rows - 16 weeks for 4 months...

Comment: @Roxy'Pro the groupBy works on the weekNumber of the PaymentDate...if there are only 4 distinct weeks available among the paymentDates, then you will get 4 rows only. For 16 weeks, there must be paymentDates spanning across 16 weeks. Is that happening in the data?

Comment: @Roxy'Pro that is probably due to your source data only having data for those 4 weeks?  if you need every week regardless of whether there is data for it you'll need to approach this a bit differently...